# Taking a huge amount of time to test 'isset' with NULL value

Tags: php

I have this array, taken from a database record:

```
array (
  'id' => '66',
  'userID' => '4786',
  'heard' => NULL,
)
```

However, the next, seems to take AGES to process:

`if((isset($check['heard'])) && ($check['heard'] != null)) {`

.. And I don't know why? Even if I just test it:

`if(isset($check['heard']) {`

It takes such a long time, and will eventually time out due to max execution time.

Previously I had it at:

`if($check)`
.. And that works fine, still does.  But I need to test 'heard'.

What the heck is going on?

Comment: Are you sure that that is the line wich is taking so much time? Did you change anything else?

Comment: Pretty damn sure.  If it take it out it works fine.  I don't get it.

Answer (score 2):

replace that line with this one...

```
if(isset($check['heard']) && $check['heard'] !== null) {
```

you had some funky syntax going on there...

Or if you just want to check `isset()` do this..

```
if(isset($check['heard'])) {
```

(you were missing the right peren)

if you know `$check['heard']` will never be zero or an empty string you could do this instead...

```
if(!empty($check['heard'])) {
```

Comment: Thanks! Although I've just discovered that to compare `null` values you must use the `===` comparison instead of simply `==`.  I think that's where it was going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

you can also go for Array key exists. as given below and check whether is is null are not

```
$m=array (
    'id'     => '66',
    'userID' => '4786',
    'heard'  => NULL,
);

if (array_key_exists("heard",$m)){
    if ($m['heard']!="")
    {
        echo "Key exists";
    }
}
```